# Spring AOP : Replace XML with annotations for transaction management?

Tags: spring, annotations, aop

I would like to know if it's possible to replace this code :

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />  
        <tx:method name="saveFile" isolation="SERIALIZABLE" propagation="REQUIRED" no-rollback-for="BusinessException" />
        <tx:method name="*" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<!--Transaction aspect-->
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="businessOperation"
        expression="execution(* com.application.app.business.*.*(..)) || execution(* com.application.app.logic..*.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="businessOperation" />
</aop:config>
```

With full annotations and no XML at all? I mean defining an aspect doing the same thing on the transaction manager.

I am able to define an aspect and pointcut but I don't see how I could get and act on the transaction manager.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Register an `TransactionInterceptor`, create a `NameMatchMethodPointcut` to match the expression you have now. On the `TransactionInterceptor` add different rules for the methods you want (to replace `tx:advice`).

Comment: what version of spring are you using?

Comment: @M.Deinum : could you share a small example of your proposal in Java please? I'm a little confused on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

What the [`<tx:advice />`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-tx/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/config/TxAdviceBeanDefinitionParser.java) does is basically register a [`TransactionInterceptor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor.html) which gets the `PlatformTransactionManager` injected and setup with different rules for the [`<tx:method />`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-tx/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/config/TxAdviceBeanDefinitionParser.java#L97) elements.

To replicate this something like the following should be done in Java based configuration.

```
@Bean
public TransactionInterceptor transactionInterceptor(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    return new TransactionInterceptor(transactionManager, transactionAttributeSource());
}

@Bean
public NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource transactionAttributeSource() {
    NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource tas = new NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource();
    RuleBasedTransactionAttribute gets = new RuleBasedTransactionAttribute();
    gets.setReadOnly(true);

    RuleBasedTransactionAttribute saveFile = new RuleBasedTransactionAttribute(8, Collections.singletonList(new NoRolebackRuleAttribute(BusinessException.class);

    Map<String, AttributeSource> matches = new HashMap<>();
    matches.put("get*", gets);
    matches.put("saveFile", saveFile);
    return tas;
}
```

Now the next part is that you need to define the point cuts manually. For this you need to construct an [`AspectJExpressionPointcutAdvisor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/aspectj/AspectJExpressionPointcutAdvisor.html). This is also what is done by the `<aop:pointcut />` tag.

```
@Bean
public AspectJExpressionPointcutAdvisor transactionAdvisor(TransactionInterceptor advice) {
    AspectJExpressionPointcutAdvisor advisor = new AspectJExpressionPointcutAdvisor();
    advisor.setAdvice(advice);
    advisor.setExpression("execution(* com.application.app.business.*.*(..)) || execution(* com.application.app.logic..*.*(..))");
    return advisor;
}
```

That should be what you need to do if you want to replicate the xml configuration. However I would suggest moving to `@Transactional` instead, which is a lot easier to setup.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72247535/3129465. the above didn't work in spring 2.x because it clashes with existing beans with same name that spring data initiate by default

Comment: This is a Spring question **not** a Spring Boot question. You are mixing/confusing Spring and Spring Boot. So basically your comment doesn't apply!

Comment: sorry, I mean *spring boot* for sure

Comment: Still the question here is about Spring and not Spring Boot so it still doesn't apply.